# External Drive Detected but not Recognized

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a 32 GB Kingston USB 3.0 pendrive which had write permission problems. After searching around and trying a USB Low Formatting Tool which never managed to get past 30%, I used the command line to "clear all" using diskpart. During the process it had an error which made it stop. After that, when I plug in the pendrive on any port, there is a connecting sound but the device is not displayed on the disk manager or on my computer.

The USB connection I use in each case to connect the pendrive is displayed on the device manager with the yellow exclamation mark, with a "Code 10" error. On the taskbar the secure hardware extraction appears but it calls the pendrive "DataTraveller 3.0" without any sub-menus. I cannot find the pendrive anywhere else.

I have done many research, and seen many Microsoft Support Articles (such as: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943104/ ) but they havn't worked.

Ideas? I don't mind loosing data, if it still isn't lost.

Sorry for my English, it isn't my first language.

Comment: If it's dead it's dead. Toss it and buy a new one.